# How to transfer constants from one loop to next one

Tags: arduino-uno

```cpp
#include "VernierLib.h"

VernierLib Vernier;

#define led 13

float sensorReading;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println(Vernier.sensorName());
  Vernier.autoID();
}

void loop() {
  float base_temp;
  base_temp = Serial.parseFloat();   
  sensorReading = Vernier.readSensor();
  Serial.print(sensorReading);
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.println(Vernier.sensorUnits());
  Serial.println(base_temp);
  if (base_temp > sensorReading) {
    digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
  } else {
    digitalWrite(led, LOW);
  }
  delay(3000);
}
```

That's the code, I have a question. When I write the temperature to Serial, it lasts only until the end of one loop.

How to keep the same temperature in the next loop?

Comment: To keep the variable value through different iterations of a function, declare it as `static`. Though your code will overwrite that value, when you use `Serial.parseFloat()`. Though that is a programming question, not an Arduino question

Comment: @chrisl thanks, but i would like to keep the same constant for like 2, 3 loops and than change it again. How would i do that?

Comment: It is unclear to me, what exactly you mean. And why 2 or 3 loops? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @chrisl , i'd like to achieve that i could anytime change the constant temperature, and when i change it should stay the same until i change it again.

Comment: constants cannot be changed ... use a variable to hold changeable data

Comment: Also asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65512883/how-do-i-change-variable-after-each-2-3-loops . Please don't crosspost.

Comment: In addition to @chrisl comment, you need to use code such as `if ( Serial.available() ) { base_temp = Serial.parseFloat(); }`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things here you need to consider.

First is that your variable is a "local" variable. This kind of variable is created at the start of each iteration, then discarded at the end of that iteration.

There's two things you can do to "fix" this:

1. Make the variable "global" - that is, move the definition out of `loop()` to the "global" scope (put it at the top of your program). It is then only created once and never discarded.
2. Make the variable "static" - that is, add the `static` keyword to it. It is then created on the first iteration only, and never discarded.

The second thing to consider is that you have no "There is no value" concept. Every iteration you parse a new float, whether there is one there or not. And if there isn't one then it just gives you `0`. So you need to come up with some way of saying "I have entered a number, so parse it". The simplest thing is just to assume that all values of 0 are "no number entered", but that of course prevents you ever entering 0 as a valid input.

Comment: A `static` variable is created before `main()` (or `setup()` on Arduinos) runs. It is initialized with a given explicit value or zeroed without.

Comment: @thebusybee Technically, yes, that's right. But the effect, as far as an Arduino user is concerned, is that it is created once on first run and stays around afterwards. Arduino users really don't need to know such technical minutiae just yet.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work (untested, but you get the idea; the explanation is in the comments):

```cpp
void loop() {
  static float base_temp = 21;     // Or whatever default starting value you want
  static float t = 0;              // A temporary store for Serial.parseFloat()

  t = Serial.parseFloat();         // Read t; if Serial.parseFloat() times out, it will return 0.00
  if (t != 0.00) {                 // If something else than 0.00 is in t
    base_temp = t;                 // Update base_temp with t
  }                                // Note: You can't set base_temp to exactly 0.00 with this set-up
  sensorReading = Vernier.readSensor();
  Serial.print(sensorReading);
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.println(Vernier.sensorUnits());
  Serial.println(base_temp);
  if (base_temp > sensorReading) {
    digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
  } else {
    digitalWrite(led, LOW);
  }
  delay(3000);
}
```

In this code `0.00` means that "no value was entered", so you can't set the temperature to *exactly* 0.00 with this set-up; 0.01 should work fine, though.